# AdminGrid get collection on tab click / load on demand

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, collection, grid

Greetings StackExchange.

I have a feature request on a admingrid. 
We are using Boost My Shop ERP for our shop.

Is it possible for make a modification on how/when to load the collection?

The module is loading 4 different collections with data into their own seperate tab in the grid.

Is where a way to only load a collection if one is active on the tab?

Here is a screenshot of the module:

[image: Admin grid loads all orders distributed in their own tabs]

Comment: Yep, it is possible with an ajax request , each time when you click on the tabs. But probably you will get loading time issue. I ;m not sure how much data do you get.

Comment: Hello Chester. Thanks for your comment. 

In the heat of battle, I did oversee the module system config, allowed the opportunity to remove the tabs and thereby the load. :)

Comment: maybe you should post an answer with this :)